# Contribute to Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

How can one contribute to Ubuntu Touch? Can we post apps for peer review?

it'll be great if someone can chalk out a guide as regards how someone can contribute to this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the official [Ubuntu Touch wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Contribute). The link you are looking for is the one on the wiki that says *Get involved!*.

Ubuntu Touch is no longer maintained as a core product by Canonical, however the [Ubports](https://ubports.com/) community is continuing development.